# Puppet Hiera Variables - Accessing Hash within Hash

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a Puppet class which uses this format to create a variable for a deep merge later.

```
$config = {
    'foo'       => {
      'fvar1'   => 'fvar1-string',
      'fvar2'   => 'fvar2-string',
    },
    'bar'  => {
      'bvar1'  => 'bvar1-string',
      'bvar2'  => 'bvar2-string',
    },
}
```

I am working to refactor the code so that the data is managed in hiera instead of within the code itself. In doing so, I would prefer to only need a single hiera lookup for each hash (`foo` and `bar`). Is this possible?

Here is what I have attempted so far:

Hiera data:

```
role::fb:
  foo:
    fvar1: 'fvar1-string'
    fvar2: 'fvar2-string'
  bar:
    bvar1: 'bvar1-string'
    bvar2: 'bvar2-string'
```

Code:

```
class test {
  $config = {
    'foo'  => hiera('role::fb::foo', undef),
    'bar'  => hiera('role::fb::bar', undef),
  }
  notify { "Config: ${config}": }
}

include test
```

Output:

```
[root@puppetclient1 ~]# puppet agent -t
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Retrieving locales
Info: Caching catalog for puppetclient1.home.arpa
Info: Applying configuration version '1684256670'
Notice: Config: {foo => , bar => }
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Notify[Config: {foo => , bar => }]/message: defined 'message' as 'Config: {foo => , bar => }'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
[root@puppetclient1 ~]#
```

My desired output is that `foo` and `bar` contain the contents of the hiera data, including `fvar{1,2}` and `bvar{1,2}` respectively.

EDIT:
John Bollinger's answer below has helped me in my understanding tremendously. I have been able to recreate the solutions in Puppet 5. However, I should have mentioned this earlier, I have a need for compatibility with Puppet 3 at the moment. When running the code against version 3.8.7, I run into a syntax error and compilation fails.

Updated code (utilizing hiera() for version compatibility here):

```
class fb {
  $config = {
    'foo'  => hiera('role::fb', undef)['foo'],
    'bar'  => hiera('role::fb', undef)['bar'],
  }
  notify { "Config: ${config}": }
}

include fb
```

Error when using Puppet 3.8.7:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Syntax error at '['; expected ']' at /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/A/manifests/fb.pp:3 on node puppetclient1.home.arpa
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Final edit:

I spoke too soon. John's suggestion stating "promote the members to top-level keys" worked like a charm. I apparently had a syntax issue during my first attempt. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most natural mapping of your data from manifest code to Hiera would be this:

```yaml
module_name::class_name::config:
  foo:
    fvar1: 'fvar1-string'
    fvar2: 'fvar2-string'
  bar:
    bvar1: 'bvar1-string'
    bvar2: 'bvar2-string'
```

The most natural way to *retrieve* that in your manifest would be via automatic data binding to a class parameter:

```
class module_name::class_name (
  $config
) {
    // ... $config data automatically looked up in Hiera ...
}
```

Automatic data binding relies on the Hiera key having the form `module_name::class_name::param_name`.

If you prefer, however, then you can still perform an explicit lookup:

```
class module_name::class_name {
  // lookup() is now the preferred data-lookup function; hiera() is deprecated
  $config = lookup('module_name::class_name::config')
}
```

Explicit lookup can be performed for any key, so if this is your target case then you are not limited to keys of the `module_name::class_name::specific_name` form.

If you want only one or the other member hash at a time, then you can retrieve the whole config and then select the wanted value from it:

```
  $foo_config = lookup('module_name::class_name::config')['foo']
```

Alternatively, if you want the ability to look up the `foo` and `bar` members individually, and are ok with losing the ability to look up the whole config at once, then you can simply promote the members to top-level keys:

```yaml
role::fb::foo:
    fvar1: 'fvar1-string'
    fvar2: 'fvar2-string'
role::fb::bar:
    bvar1: 'bvar1-string'
    bvar2: 'bvar2-string'
```

---

Additional note: following @MattSchuchard's comment, if you want `lookup()` to provide a default value, even `undef`, when the key is not found, then you need to specify that in the `lookup()` call.  This is different from the behavior of the legacy `hiera()` function. There's more than one way to do that, but if you want to default to `undef` as `hiera()` did, then the simplest is to add the three optional arguments to the `lookup()` call, with the last of those being the wanted default value:

```
  $config = lookup('module_name::class_name::config', Hash, 'first', undef)
```

If you do not specify a default and the requested key is not found, then catalog building will fail.

Comment: 100% complete and best advice, but super minor note that the original `hiera` function in the question provided a default value of `undef` for some unspecified reason, and that threfore the equivalent `lookup` would be `$config = lookup('module_name::class_name::config', undef, undef, undef)` (third `undef` being the default).

Comment: Thanks, @MattSchuchard, I added some remarks about default values.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! This really helps me put the pieces together. @JohnBollinger, unfortunately, I left out a key part of my initial question, a need for compatibility with Puppet 3. I have edited my question in hopes of clarifying the situation. I was, however, able to apply your solutions when testing against Puppet 5. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: Please disregard my last comment. I made a mistake on my end. I also added a final edit to my original question. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you, @JG7.  For the record, the only part of this answer that is specific to newer Puppet is the use of the `lookup()` function (and its details) in place of the `hiera()` function.  The format of the data files, remarks about automated data binding, *etc*. are all the same from Puppet 3 through Puppet 7.

Comment: @MattSchuchard -- Your comment states "provided a default valye of undef for some unspecified reason." This was my (uneducated) choice. Do you have a recommendation regarding this? Or perhaps know of some reading material that might apply to this situation?